# Running a file after extracting from Zip 7

Tags: excel, autorun, winzip

I have a large of files including MyExcel.xlsm (macro enabled file). A few jpeg file and a power point presentation: mypresentation.pptm (macro enabled file)

I want to put pack them in a exe file. This I am able to do using zip 7.

Issue is, I would to have the excel sheet running after the extraction is completed.

Answer (score 1):

run after extracting:

https://superuser.com/questions/42788/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-file-after-extraction-from-a-7-zip-self-extracting-a

if it doesn't work with "yourexcel" as a command try "excel" and pass the filename as an argument (maybe a bit different).